What is the meaning for the WSDI climate index when takes values between 0<=5?
The definition of the WSDI Index is "the annual count of days with at least 6 consecutive days when TX > 90th percentile", according to Climdex (https://www.climdex.org/learn/indices/#index-WSDI) and other sources.
That definition must imply that the minimun value is 6: given that the index counts each day that has at least 6 consecutive days with the defined temperature.
In fact, the description from Copernicus (EU) about the minumum values is: "For WSDI the lowest number (other than zero) is 5, as the spells need to be this long to be classed as a spell."
Despite the fact that they take 5 days and not 6 to define a warm spell, as Climdex does, they specify that the minimum value needs to be 5 (besides 0).
But the WSDI datasets downloaded from CLIMDEX (and other local sources) have values between 0 and 6. See below a sample dataset from a simulation model for yearly WSDI values between 1960 and 1990, in days.
What do these values mean?
Any orientation about how these values should be interpreted will be of great help.
A possibility is that these are values that should not be there, and need to be deleted, but as they are found in several datasets from different sources, maybe the explanation is another.

